# How to change data source object based on database name defined in applicationcontext.xml at runtime

Tags: spring, hibernate

when I am accessing application, is it possible to pass different mysql database names to applicationcontext.xml data source bean. In my application I am using spring and hibernate frameworks. please answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to store all database information in a properties file like :

```
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = letmein
jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database-url
```

and in xml file :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
```

you should change jdbd.url when you accessing the application , right ?

I think with InputStream you can import the file in java and edit your properties file and change jdbc.url .

2) You can also change the url with method setUrl(string s) and run the method setDataSource again . Please see here [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)